# Create collection that includes itself

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of nodes and each node could have a parent node. If the parent node exists I would like to insert it as a child (ie: the parent would become its own child) but I'm struggling to figure out a way to do this with linq if possible.

My non linq attempt:

```
private IList<IPageNode> addParentNode(IList<IPageNode> nodes) {
    if (nodes[0].parent == null) return nodes;
    var parentWithoutChildren = new PageNode {
            name = nodes[0].parent.name,
            isNavigable = nodes[0].parent.isNavigable,
            url = nodes[0].parent.url,
            children = null,
            parent = null
        };
    nodes.Insert(0, parentWithoutChildren);
    return nodes;
}
```

What I have so far works but there are two issue:

1. It's not with linq and I'm assuming that linq would be the most efficient/effective way to accomplish this.
2. The object that's passed in is being manipulated, changed and returned and I can't have that happen. I know I could just create a new object and return that but I'd like to learn something new if it's possible.

Comment: "It's not with linq and I want it to be." - Why does everyone always think that linq is the answer to every problem? It really isn't. LINQ is a great tool when used in the right places. That does **not mean** that you should go looking for *other places* to use it. Sometimes you should use *other tools*.

Comment: Its not a good idea to modify the original collection in a  linq statement. The iteration process becomes brittle if the underlying iterables are altered by the iteration itself.  You probably want to take the hit and either collect unparented nodes as part of a pre-processing step, or just write your query so it knows what to do with unparented nodes

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree with you. Perhaps I should rephrase that. What I'm really trying to say is that I'd like to get this done in the most efficient/effective way, and I was being presumptious, but I was thinking it was with linq.

Comment: @theodox that's exactly what I was trying to avoid, and the current method modifies the existing collection. My goal is to return a new collection and if possible do it with linq.

Comment: @MarcGravell when you have a hummer, everything looks like a nail :)

Comment: Everything looks like a hammer? :)

Comment: the new collection will have different state than the original (the parent fields will be set differently) -- this may make for bugs down the road since you can't assume that the parent = self convention always applies (and watch out if you want to traverse UP the chain too!)   What about an instance method that returns self when the parent is null but is clearly marked as "i'm the method for when you want to pretend i'm my own parent" ?  Then you can iterate in linq using that method without changing or duping the collection

Comment: "Parent becomes its own child." Are you sure you really want to do that? I made the mistake of writing something like that once. It wasn't pretty and it ended up being full of special cases to handle that silliness. You might want to re-think your approach.

Comment: I have to say that, `LINQ` is not the best. It requires more step to reach to the actual `loop`, it's just for convenient, makes code cleaner, shorter, more maintainable. However a pure `for` on an appropriate `collection structure` will be better in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the question is: Do you want to return a different list containing the same objects (and possibly an additional one) or do you want to return a new list of new objects?

Assuming the former:

```
public static IEnumerable<IPageNode> WithClonedParent(this IList<IPageNode> list)
{
    var newParent = list.First().CloneParentIfSet();
    if (newParent)
    {
         yield return newParent;
    }
    foreach (var node in list)
    {
         yield return node;
    }
}
```

`CloneParentIfSet` could be an extension method for `IPageNode` which does what you currently do in your `new PageNode` statement.

Then you can use it like this: `nodes.WithClonedParent()` which will be a new collection.

Not necessarily more efficient but maybe a bit more elegant (IMHO).